# cannot execute any command using sudo on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, sudo, yocto

I cannot execute any command using sudo. I get this error

> -sh: sudo: command not found

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First: if you are already `root`, you do not need `sudo`.

Second: if this is a `yocto`-based image as the question tag suggests, then there is no `apt-get` either. This is the "debianoid" way of installing things and does not apply to prebuilt-image based distributions as `yocto` provides them. So you have two options:

1. Change to `ubuntu` or `debian` (or any derivative thereof), then this approach will apply.
2. Use the `yocto`/`OpenEmbedded` way of installing things. This is unfortunately not exactly trivial, so you better get started here then: [Yocto Projct Quick Start](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6.1/brief-yoctoprojectqs/brief-yoctoprojectqs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check the user you log in.

- If you are the root user, you have the super access right yet.
- If not, you need to change your configuration in your yocto project like this

  EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "\
      usermod -p 'passowrd' root; \
  "